# devise current_user is throwing erros when no one logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

```
<p><% if current_user.admin == true %>
```

is giving me errors of

```
undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass
```

when no one is logged in.  This is because you can not call admin on nil, and current_user is nil because no one is logged in.  How can I get everything to display normally if no one is logged in? Considering this is the home page, and I am just calling current_user.admin to authenticate who can use Mercury cms.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: As an alternative to Nick's method, you could also call `current_user.try(:admin)`, which will return nil instead of raising an exception. See http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if current user exists.

Try this code

```
<p><% if current_user && current_user.admin == true %>
```

Comment: thanks exactly what I was looking for, I will accept when the time limit is up